# Metal app on macOS lags when for example using the menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, metal, metalkit

I'm playing around with Metal and MetalKit on macOS. It works fine for the most part, but in everything I've built so far the rendering will lag for a brief moment when I do things in the menu bar or hover my mouse over the dock. It's kind of annoying.

The easiest way to reproduce this effect is by trying Apple's own ['Device Selection and Fallback for Graphics Rendering' Sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/choosing_gpus_on_mac/device_selection_and_fallback_for_graphics_rendering). I've observed the issue on macOS 10.13 and 10.14.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Core Animation won't lag like that, but it's not suitable for what I would like to do. I believe it's built on top of Metal these days though, making me believe that it should be possible to get rid of the lag.

Comment: My guess is that this is due to compositing. When another window overlaps your Metal view, the window server has to composite them together. When nothing overlaps, it's possible that Metal renders directly to the screen's frame buffer. It may help to leave vsync enabled if you've disabled it (setting `displaySyncEnabled` on the `CAMetalLayer`) and/or set `presentsWithTransaction` on the view to true.

Comment: So I finally got around to trying that. `displaySyncEnabled` is set, I'm using `MTKView` and I haven't really changed any of the defaults. The lagging is still happening though.

Comment: I have played with it a little more and I realised the lagging happens even when nothing overlaps the Metal view. I also oberseved that it only lags when I close a menu in the top menu bar, it doesn't when I open it.

Comment: Hmm. Menus fade out when you dismiss them. Could be related to that. They don't fade out when you switch menus or move your mouse to a part of the menu bar with no menus. Does that help isolate it? Also, you didn't indicate if you set `presentsWithTransaction` to true and if that helped.

Comment: I've tried `presentWithTransaction` now. It causes the view to only update when I resize the window for example (I assume because that triggers a `CATransaction`. The resizing also becomes incredibly slow to react.

Comment: I've also considered your hint and played with the menus etc. a little more. I realised that the lagging related to the menu bar only occurs when closing a menu belonging to the app that is running Metal. Opening or hovering doesn't cause lag, neither does any action in the menu bar when a different app's window is active(i.e. the menu bar relates to that app). I also tried opening other apps and windows. Unless they had a lot of loading to do that didn't cause lagging either. I thought that maybe the menu bar runs on the main thread, delaying the call to `draw` of `MTKView`s delegate?

Comment: I had the same issue. I configured the MTKView to receive manual draw calls (by setting self.enableSetNeedsDisplay = NO and self.paused = YES).  Then, make your draw call from the CVDisplayLink callback instead, and all works -- no stutter on a menu mouseUp.